# Cleanest/most efficient way to select the object which has the minimum key value

Tags: javascript

I have several objects in JavaScript, but I need to select one of them, based on it having the minimum value of a certain key.

I can run a for loop finding the value, and then another loop matching the value back to the structure, but this seems wasteful to me.

```
var obj1 = {
  'product' : 'cake',
  'price' : 2
}
var obj2 = {
  'product' : 'cake',
  'price' : 3
}
```

In this case, I would like obj1 to be selected to move on with further calculations.

Comment: There's no JSON there. Only JavaScript.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Start by putting them into an array so that you can properly loop them :-)

Comment: "*I can run a for loop finding the value*" - could you show us how you would have written that loop? It's easy to find both the value and the object at the same time.

Comment: depending on the data, it might be quickest to sort and grab the endcap, and it will likely be the simplest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If objects are stored in an array, ES6 methods are the way to go.
[`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the idiomatic way to achieve your use case :

```
const objs = [
  {
    'product' : 'cake',
    'price' : 2
  },
  {
    'product' : 'cake',
    'price' : 3
  }
]

const minObj = objs.reduce((minObjSoFar, currentObj) => {
  if(!minObjSoFar || currentObj.price < minObjSoFar.price)
    return currentObj;
  return minObjSoFar;
}, null);
```

If `minObj` is `null`, it means the array was empty. If it's OK to rely on exceptions to indicate that the array is empty, you can omit the initial value and write simpler code

```
const minObj = objs.reduce((minObjSoFar, currentObj) => {
  if(currentObj.price < minObjSoFar.price)
    return currentObj;
  return minObjSoFar;
});
```

Comment: You might want to start with a proper initial value, e.g. `{product: null, price: Infinity}`.

Comment: If no initial value is specified, the first element of the array is used. It suits this use case :)

Comment: …and throws an exception in case of an empty array, which one should try to avoid.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's better to have values `null` and `Infinity` floating around in the code, instead of an exception being raised, in the case where an empty array is (presumably accidentally) passed to this function. It means you'd need to explicitly check for the return value every time you use the result, it's not clear this is less work than just using a `try/catch`.

Comment: I would argue this is a matter of opinion, though `undefined` might be a better choice than `null`. To me, all three answers are valid. What matters is to chose the pattern that is most coherent with the rest of the codebase.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Exceptions can be used as well if you choose them deliberately, they might indeed be simpler in some uses cases. It always depends on what you want to do with the minimum value. However, personally I find that specifying a value like `Infinity` is better precisely because of the work it causes - so that nobody will forget to handle this edge case.

Comment: @debel27 You cannot use `null` as the initial value, that would cause an exception when trying to access the `.price` property on it. Yes, one could guard against that with an extra condition, but I think passing `{price: Infinity}` makes everything simpler.

Comment: Totally agree it's a matter of opinion, I didn't say "I'm right", just "I'm not convinced" (that the one way is better) :) (Btw I would upvote your comments on this, but apparently I've run out of votes for the day. I have no idea why SO limits this...)

Comment: No harm done ! This is the kind of discussions that benefit to everyone. Heck, I never considered reduce would throw an exception before 20 minutes ago !

Answer (score 1):

You could assemble an array and use [lodash minBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#minBy)

```
const objs = [
  {
    'product' : 'cake',
    'price' : 2
  },
  {
    'product' : 'cake',
    'price' : 3
  }
]
return _.minBy(objs, 'price');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fine with the "idiomatic" way proposed by @debel27, but a good old for loop would do in the same way.

```
var obj1 = {
'product' : 'cake',
'price' : 2
}
var obj2 = {
'product' : 'cake',
'price' : 3
}

var arr = [obj1, obj2]

var objWithMinPrice = selectWithMinimumPrice(arr)

function selectWithMinimumPrice(inputArr) {
    if (!(inputArr && Array.isArray(inputArr) && inputArr.length > 0))
        return null

    var res = inputArr[0];

    for(var i = 1; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
        if (inputArr[i].price < res.price)
            res = inputArr[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

And it would still probably be marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objs = [
  { product : 'shampoo', price : 3 },
  { product : 'cake', price : 2 },
];

const cheapestObj = objs.reduce(
  (store, current) => current.price < store.price ? current : store,
  { price: Infinity }
);
```

May be refactored like:

```js
const objs = [
  { product : 'shampoo', price : 3 },
  { product : 'cake', price : 2 },
];

const reducer = (store, current) => current.price < store.price ? current : store;

const cheapestObj = objs.reduce(reducer, { price: Infinity });
```

then:

```js
const objs = [
  { product : 'shampoo', price : 3 },
  { product : 'cake', price : 2 },
];

const reduceBy = field => (store, current) => current[field] < store[field] ? current : store;

const cheapestObj = objs.reduce(reduceBy('price'), { price: Infinity });
```

You may find [more information about Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on MDN

Answer (score 0):

This is not so good as using `reduce()`, but you can first get the minimum value of the `key` and then use [Array:find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first item having that value on the related `key`:

```js
const items = [
    {'product': 'cake', 'price': 2},
    {'product': 'cake', 'price': 3},
    {'product': 'coffee', 'price': 1},
];

let minPrice = Math.min(...items.map(({price}) => price));
let res = items.find(x => x.price === minPrice);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This double loop is precisely what the OP is trying to avoid (as stated in his question). But it sure does look clean. Is there any reason you're spreading `items.map` before passing it to `Math.min` ?

Comment: @debel27 Without spread don't work (`map()` returns an array). I know is not so good in performance as using `reduce()`, I have commented that, but it is just another alternative for the `two loops` the OP was trying to use.